# Simplify $(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee \neg q) $ to obtain $ (p \vee(q \wedge \neg q))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I am unable to simplify the equation $$
(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee \neg q)
$$ to $$
(p \vee(q \wedge \neg q))
$$.

[image: Original Book Question]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Distributivity of $\vee$ on $\wedge$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absorption in a chain.

$$(p\lor q)\land (p\lor \lnot q)$$

$$=(p\land p)\lor (p\land q)\lor(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q \land\lnot q)\quad(\text{distribution)}$$

$$=p\lor (p\land q)\lor(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q \land\lnot q)\quad(\text{idempotence)}$$

$$=p\lor(p\land \lnot q) \lor (q \land\lnot q)\quad(\text{absorption)}$$

$$=p \lor (q \land\lnot q)\quad(\text{absorption)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$q \wedge \neg q$ is always false, so $(p \vee(q \wedge \neg q))=p$.

If $p$ is true, $(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee \neg q)$ will be "true and true", it therefore is true. Conversely, if $p$ is false, $(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee \neg q)$ will be "false and false", it therefore is false. Thus, $(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee \neg q)=p=(p \vee(q \wedge \neg q))$.

Comment: Truth tables are generally discouraged as a method of proof in propositional logic classes. The point is to use the rules of inference to demonstrate equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Transforming this to Binary Notations as it makes it slightly simpler to handle with
$\displaystyle ( p+q) *( p+\overline{q}) \ =\ pp+p\overline{q} \ +\ qp\ +\ q\overline{q} \ =\ p+p\overline{q} +qp\ =\ p( 1+\overline{q}) +qp$
$\displaystyle p+pq\ =\ p( 1+q) \ =\ p$
Now the second statement is $\displaystyle p+( q*\overline{q}) \ =\ p$
Since both statements are equating to the same value, both statements have to be equal to each other.